# Чтение массива из файла.

Tags: winapi, массивы, delphi, файлы

Есть файл mat.dat объёмом в 1000 байт. Как быстро записать оттуда каждый байт в элемент одномерного массива с 1000-ю элементами типа byte? Дать пример кода, если не сложно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. В Delphi есть [BlockRead](http://www.delphibasics.ru/BlockRead.php).
2. В WinAPI есть [ReadFile](http://vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Menage_files/fn_readfile.htm) для чтения из файла или [MapViewOfFile](http://vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Menage_files/fn_mapviewoffile.htm) для отображения файла в память.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с файлами типа .dat рекомендуется использовать блочное считывание/запись данных, так как этот метод имеет преимущества в быстродействии перед, например, использованием стандартных файловых потоков класса  `TFileStream`. **Вот пример:**

```
...
var 
f:File;
b:BYTE;
i:integer;
...
begin
AssignFile(f,'C:\Data.dat');
Reset(f,1);
for i:=1 to 1000 do
begin
BlockRead(f,b,1);
...
// что-то делаем с каждым считанным байтом
end;

CloseFile(F);

end;
```

Comment: @Asen, зачем цикл? Можно же сразу считать 1000 элементов в массив:

    BlockRead(f,ArrOfBytes,1000);

Comment: @insolor, абсолютно с вами согласен! Но для наглядности и простоты решил продемонстрировать таким образом...

Comment: @Asen, спорно. Чтение большого блока за 1 раз гораздо нагляднее (и быстрее) чтения по 1 байту в цикле.

И в измененном варианте программа будет пытаться прочитать по 1000 * 4 * 4 байт, так что первый вариант был правильнее.

Comment: @insolor, не спорно, а абсолютно бесспорно, читать надо **большими блоками**. 

@Asen, более того, это безусловно наглядней.

Comment: Что-что? Чтение по одному байтику *имеет преимущества в быстродействии*?

Comment: @karmadro4......

    блочное считывание/запись данных имеет преимущества в быстродействии